# c# text box - Accept only floating point numbers inside a range

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, validation

Whenever the user tries to enter a number not in the range `[0, 24]` it should show an error message. My code to accept floating point numbers is as follows. How can I modify it to add range validation?

```
private void h(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{        
   try
   {
      float time = float.Parse(hours.Text);
   }
   catch
   { 
      label2.Text = "enter proper value ";
      hours.Text = " ";
   } 
}
```

Comment: `if(time > 0 && time < 24)` ??

Comment: you can use a simple regex and validate the input against the regex. Again this regex can be read from a config file so that you can plug any validation logic and change the behavior w/o application recompile at runtime

Answer (score 2):

I know SO discourages just posting a link as an answer but in the case the link is a direct and full answer to the question.

[Validation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.aspx)

Comment: You can summarize the content contained in the link to provide a useful answer, and then provide the link for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `float.TryParse`, rather than building a try-catch block in case the parse fails.  `TryParse` will return the value of the parse in the `out` variable, and true if the parse is successful and false if it isn't.  Combine that with a check to see if the number is between 0 and 24, and you have something that looks like this:

```
float parsedValue;

// If the parse fails, or the parsed value is less than 0 or greater than 24,
// show an error message
if (!float.TryParse(hours.Text, out parsedValue) || parsedValue < 0 || parsedValue > 24)
{
    label2.Text = "Enter a value from 0 to 24";
    hours.Text = " ";
}
```